# Pass object with routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I wanted to pass one object with routerLink. I found lot but, didn't get any satisfied answer. I am new to angular.

**user.component.html**

```
<button type="button" routerLink="/admin">Add Event</button>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public user: UserOperator = new UserOperator({});
```

I wanted to pass above user object to with button routerLink.

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
]
```

I am working on Angular 7. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't provide objects to your link. A link is a string. You have several options to do what you want : services, stores, static data, resolvers ... But using the link is not one of them.

Comment: I finally found out how to add an object as query params: <a [routerLink]="['/editinventoryitem',item.id]" [queryParams]="this.viewState">Edit</a> (My viewState class has key-value pairs... [key: string]: any;)  (I'm on Angular v14 at the moment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a npm package for Angular which extends router: angular2-navigate-with-data

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-navigate-with-data

I'm using it with Angular 6 and pretty sure it works also with 7.
Example use:

import package in app.module file: `import "angular2-navigate-with-data";`

```javascript
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

class PageOne {
    constructor (private router: Router){}

    public redirect() {
        this.router.navigateByData({
            url: ["/PageTwo"],
            data: [1,2,3,4,5], //data - <any> type
            //extras: {} - <NavigationExtras> type, optional parameter
        });
    }
}


import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit} from "@angular/core";

class PageTwo implements OnInit {
    constructor (private router: Router){}

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.router.getNavigatedData()); //output [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can encode your object into the string and pass it through the query params.

**component.html**

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="[getLink()]">Add Event</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
...

getLink(): string {
    return `/admin?state=${btoa(JSON.stringify(this.user))}`;
}

...
```

**another.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
       let user = new UserOperator(JSON.parse(atob(params['state']))); 
   });
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, and without installing a package.

Answer (score 0):

```
// import routes
import { Routes, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

// define route in construct

// app.module set route
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin\:obj', component: AdminComponent },
]

//make function in ts
redirect(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin/'+user);
}

// your button
<button type="button" (click)="redirect()">Add Event</button>
```